# Is it possible to assign multiple Oracle ref cursor to one

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa, ref-cursor

As said in the title, I would like to know if it's possible to assign multiple ref cursor (in Oracle Stored procedure) to one:
Like the following code:
....

```
    create or replace procedure assign_ref_cursor(result_cur out sys_refcursor)
    as
    cursor1 sys_refcursor;
    cursor2 sys_refcursor;
    cursor3 sys_refcursor;
    
    -- expected result:
    result_cur[0] = cursor1
    result_cur[1] = cursor2
    result_cur[2] = cursor3
...
return  result_cur;
```

...
Well, what it would be nice, it's to have the whole result of each ref_cursor in one.

The reason for that is because I'm retrieving data (multiple ref cursor) from stored procedure using Spring data JPA. But apparently there is no solution to retrieve multiple ref cursor using javax.persistence.storedprocedurequery... despite days of google search...

So I imagined the solution to change the Oracle stored procedure to return only one ref_cursor, that "aggregate" the different ref_cursor.

Following the question of Alex, here is an **UPDATE**

I tried to call three OUT ref cursor parameters using:

```
StoredProcedureQuery proc = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("myStoredProc");
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("cursor1", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("cursor2", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
...
List<Object[]> listOfObjects =  proc.getResultList();
```

But **listOfObjects** contains only the content of **cursor1**
No way to get the content of **cursor2**...

Comment: Where are the three cursors coming from - are you opening them within that procedure?

Comment: Why can't you call a procedure with three OUT ref cursor parameters? [That seems to be supported](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html); or is it a Strong/JPA restirction?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response: I did an update to respond to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have something like:

```
open cursor1 for <query1>;
open cursor2 for <query2>;
open cursor3 for <query3>;
```

then you could combine them as [cursor expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CURSOR-Expressions.html#GUID-B28362BE-8831-4687-89CF-9F77DB3698D2) in one result:

```
open result_cur for
  select cursor(<query1>) as cursor1,
         cursor(<query2>) as cursor2,
         cursor(<query3>) as cursor3
  from dual;
```

If you're returning other data you can include more 'normal' columns as well and make that main query against a real table instead of dual, of course.

Comment: I tried your solution: I achivied to combine the ref_cursors in one result. But from java part, I have a "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -10".

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

Workaround by getting a connection from Hibernate EntityManager and then using CallableStatement.

```
// Session = org.hibernate.Session
// entityManager = javax.persistence.EntityManager
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(new Work() {
@Override
public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    // do something useful
    try (CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{CALL TEST_PACKAGE.GETCURSORS(?,?,?)}")) {
        cs.setInt(1, 1);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);
        ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(3);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int a = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        while (rs1.next()) {
            int b = rs1.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```